What's the continuous $\mathbb C^0$ version for immersion? I'm trying to see if topological embeddings are 'topological immersions.'
A 'smooth embedding' $f: M \to N$ between smooth ($m$,$n$)-manifolds ($M$,$N$) is a smooth map that is both a smooth immersion and a topological embedding, which is simply defined as that the range-restricted map $\tilde f: M \to f(M)$ is a homeomorphism (i.e. $f$ is a 'homeomorphism onto its image' or something).
It's been awhile since I've done this. I wonder if 'topological embedding' has the privilege of not having 'topological immersion' as part of the definition? Or if 'topological immersion' is indeed part of being homeomorphism ono its image? I imagine the definition of 'topological immersion' is the same as smooth immersion but replace $\mathbb C^\infty$ with $\mathbb C^0$.

"Immersion" is all about the derivative map. There is none in the $C^0$ setting. Smooth immersions are local embeddings; the topology governs the global behavior.

"I imagine the definition of 'topological immersion' is the same as smooth immersion but replace $C^\infty$ with $C^0$" How are you imagining this? Because being an immersion is a statement about the differential of a map, but in the $C^0$-world there is no notion of differential. Please tell us what you have in mind here.

@BenSteffan I define germ at point as for $C^0$ instead of $C^\infty$. Then point-derivation, then tangent vector at a point, then tangent space at a point, then differential at a point. Why can't I do this?

@TedShifrin I define germ at point as for $C^0$ instead of $C^\infty$. Then point-derivation, then tangent vector at a point, then tangent space at a point, then differential at a point. Why can't I do this?

@BCLC Good question! You can make this definition, but it unfortunately turns out that the object you get is badly behaved: see this question (there's a better reference for this somewhere on MO but I can't find it right now, sry).

So how are you making these definitions? As a side remark, when you're in the $C^1$ world instead of the $C^\infty$ world, derivations lead to an infinite-dimensional notion of tangent space. Ah, I see this is exactly the point raised in the post @Ben just linked. I can give a reference to an exercise in Spivak, Vol. 1, regarding this, if you need it.

See here for a discussion of different notions of topological immersions. It is primarily used in geometric topology for maps of topological manifolds. Incidentally, there are topological notions of tangent bundles (see here) but they are much more subtle than what you see in differential topology textbooks.

@BenSteffan thanks. oh what a relief that the idea of topological immersion doesn't have the same answer as the topological manifold thing ... right?

Not quite sure I understand what you mean by "same answer." Do follow the links Moishe Kohan gave you one comment above, but note that words like "immersion" and "submersion" aren't commonly used in the world of topological manifolds (to the best of my knowledge).

@TedShifrin ok thanks ... in short 'topological embedding' INDEED HAS the privilege of not having 'topological immersion' as part of the definition. but in the 1st place 'topological immersion' is for some weirdly complex/complicated reason NOT simply $C^\infty$ replaced with $C^1$?

@BenSteffan I mean in the other question you were like 'duh there's no such thing as topological atlas because it's included in topological manifold' . so here i thought it there would be a similar thing like 'there's no such thing as topological immersion because it's included in topological manifold somehow.' so definitely topological immersion is a non-trivial thing?

@MoisheKohan how come in your answer there's seemingly no issue of like 'words like "immersion" and "submersion" aren't commonly used in the world of topological manifolds (to the best of my knowledge)' or 'infinite-dimensional notion of tangent space' or 'unfortunately turns out that the object you get is badly behaved' as Ted Shifrin & Ben Steffan said above?

@BCLC At the very least it's not at all obvious what the word "topological immersion" should mean, or what a topological tangent space should be and if there's a way to carry over these definitions from the more structured setting of differentiable manifolds in a way that preserves enough of the properties to be worthwhile.

Because we are different people, perhaps?
